# Pass in wrong class still works?

Tags: python, super

Usually super works like the following in Python:

```
class SubClass(MyParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(**SubClass**, self).__init__()
```

But recently I found something like the following also works? No crash, behaviors as expected:

```
class SubClass(MyParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(**MyParentClass**, self).__init__()
```

How come? What does the second case mean?

Answer (score 3):

`super(MyParentClass, self).__init__()` Will call grandparent class  (If it has one)

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("BaseClass")


class MyParentClass(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        print("MyParentClass")


class SubClass(MyParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__()


class SubClassTwo(MyParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyParentClass, self).__init__()


SubClass() # output: MyParentClass
SubClassTwo()  # output: BaseClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the behaviour it's not the same.

From the documentation of `super()` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)):

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
>   sibling class of type.

So if you have:

```
class MyParentClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print('MyParentClass.__init__ called!')

class SubClass(MyParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyParentClass, self).__init__()
```

The call:

```
super(MyParentClass, self).__init__()
```

has no effect, because `MyParentClass` has no parents but `object`.

If you call:

```
super(SubClass, self).__init__()
```

It will print:

```
MyParentClass.__init__ called!
```

Because `SubClass` has one parent, `MyParentClass`.

Comment: *because MyParentClass has no parents* is not true, the parent is `object`.

Comment: @heemayl that's true, every class has parent `object`. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `super` says (in part):](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

> `super([type[, object-or-type]])`
>
> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
>   sibling class of `type`. This is useful for accessing inherited methods
>   that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that
>   used by `getattr()` except that the type itself is skipped.

So `super(MyParentClass, self)` resolves to a proxy object that will pass method calls through to the parents and siblings of `MyParentClass`.  It shouldn't be surprising that this works.  If your parent class is

```
class MyParentClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        super(MyParentClass, self).__init__(kwargs)
```

Then when you make a `SubClass` object, the `self` in the `MyParentClass` `super` call is a `SubClass` instance.